# How to add a condition in a formula field to update only if the record is created by a user with particular profile

Tags: formula-field

How to add a condition in a formula field to update only if the record is created by a user with a particular profile.

```
IF(f2== FALSE &&  **$Profile.Name == "abc User"**, 'HI',
'Hello')
```

1. Is this correct?
2. Does this check owner of the record?
3. Should we write something like
   `Owner.profile.name == "Abc User"  or Owner.id == '1234332d'` ?
4. How do I check the `CreatedBy` criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your question is phrased makes it seem like you have a misunderstanding around formula fields.

A formula field is a calculated field - it doesn't exist in the database and the field's value is calculated each time the formula field is accessed (i.e. loaded from the database) or when explicitly [recalculated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Formula.htm). The formula doesn't define how the field is "updated"; it simply provides a means to calculate the value to be returned when querying the field.

I think you need to re-state your question. However, going on what you currently ask:

If you are wanting the formula to return a specific value (here I assume a string) if the object was created by a user with a given profile, and null/empty otherwise, you need something like:

```
IF(f1__c == '' &&
       f2 == FALSE &&
       CreatedBy.Profile.Name = 'The Profile Name',
   'The Value',
   '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of an **IF** logical function is similar to,

```
IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

It has three parameters. And **AND** has the following syntax,

`AND(condition_first, condition_true)` returns true if both condition are true,

So, in your case, you should use something like,

```
IF(
AND(
AND(f1__c == NULL, f2__c == FALSE),
$Profile.Name == 'System Administrator'),
'SOME_VALUE', NULL)
```

So,

1. Since the IF logical function takes three arguments, it'll generate a syntax error.
2. We can get the Owner of the record in a similar way using `$USER.Id`.
3. `$Profile.Name && OwnerId` would work.
4. You can directly reference  `CreatedById` field in your formula.

And as `Phil` mentioned, instead of AND function, inline && should be it, so we can use it simply as,

```
IF(
    f1__c == NULL && f2__c == FALSE && $Profile.Name == 'System Administrator',
    'SOME_VALUE', NULL)
```

Comment: You can use && as an inline operator instead of the AND function. You have missed the point about the owner vs observing user.

Comment: I am not worried about IF condition here.